# Schengen visa issued to South African refugee travel document

Tags: schengen-visas, south-africa, refugees

I'm from the DR Congo and I have a refugee travel document issued by South Africa. Can I get a Schengen visa to travel to Germany with it? Does the German consulate issue visas to such a passport?

Comment: Yes. That is the whole point of the refugee travel document!

Answer (score 1):

Germany does require a visa for those holding refugee travel documents and it does issue visas to those holding such a document. No one can predict whether it will.

Use the [German Consular and Legal Section](https://southafrica.diplo.de/sa-en/sa-consular/sa-visa1) website to take you through the application process, get the forms you need to complete (either download or electonically and printed).